# How to parse json key value pair where one of the key having json value as a string

Tags: java, json

I have json as below as a response, where i have json as string in one of the key (i.e. SubSecData)

```
"CreatedTimestamp": "2019-10-26T11:28:06.732",
"FromBucket": "AVAILABLE",
"Country": "",
"Process": null,
"InfoId": "",
"ItemsShipped": 0,
"InventoryTypeId": "",
"ItemId": "ITEM02",
"ReasonCodeId": "",
"UpdatedBy": "admin@1",
"SubSecData": "{\"Spec\":\"ReceiptId\",\"Description\":\"Info for 
Receipt\",\"Definition\":{\"Company\":\"***\",\"Season\":\"string\",\"SeasonYear\":\"string\",\"Style\":\"string\",\"StyleSuffix\":\"string\",\"Color\":\"string\",\"ColorSuffix\":\"string\",\"Dimension\":\"string\",\"Code\":\"string\",\"Description\":\"string\",\"ItemId\":\"ITEM02\",\"Description\":\"string\"},\"SubItemFields\":{\"TypeId\":\"\",\"ProcStatusId\":\"\",\"BatchNumber\":\"\",\"Attribute1\":\"\",\"Attribute2\":\"\",\"Attribute3\":\"\",\"InventoryAttribute4\":\"\",\"InventoryAttribute5\":\"\",\"CountryOfOrigin\":\"\",\"ExpirationDate\":\"***\",\"ManufactureDate\":\"***\",\"VendorId\":\"\"},\"InfoFields\":{\"FromBucket\":\"AVAILABLE\",\"ToBucket\":\"AVAILABLE\",\"AdjustmentQty\":\"1\",\"Quantity\":\"1\",\"AdjustmentType\":\"ADD\",\"AdjustedType\":\"ADD\",\"WeightedQty\":\"1.0\",\"WeightedType\":\"ADD\",\"InfoIncId\":\"GHJ686868585\",\"PpnType\":\"IPPN\",\"BWCId\":\"VABWC23969237\"},\"Variances\":{\"\":\"\",\"UnitsReceived\":\"\",\"ItemsShipped\":\"\",\"ItemsReceived\":\"\",\"ReceiptComplete\":\"\"}}",
"TransactionCode": "",
```

I need to read the data for SubSecData and print them as key, value pairs using java so that i can assert them with the expected key value pairs

I have tried below code and stuck and don't know how to proceed further

```
public validateNestedJson(expectedKeyValuePairs)
{
    JSONObject getAPIJSONData= new JSONObject(getAPIResponse);
    if (getAPIJSONData.get("SubSecData") != null)
    {
        log.info("Parsing Json Data");
        //iterate expectedKeyValuePairs times
        for(expectedKeyValuePairs=0; expectedKeyValuePairs.length; expectedKeyValuePairs++) {
          //print all the SubSecData elements which match expected KeyValuePairs
          getAPIJSONData.get("SubSecData").<k,v>toHashMap();
        }
          return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
        //print actualvalues - if one or more values doesn't match
    }
}
```

I will call the "validateNestedJson" method as below

```
HashMap<String, String> expectedKeyValuePairs;
expectedKeyValuePairs.put("Description","String");
expectedKeyValuePairs.put("ItemId","ITEM02");
Boolean result = validateNestedJson (expectedKeyValuePairs);
```

Output should be true or false. If false, need to print the values which are false

```
SubSecData.Description = Array
SubSecData.ItemId = ITEM01
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be Java? `for(getAPIJSONData.each.get(expectedKeyValuePairs.key) {`???? What is `each`? Why aren't `()` balanced? --- What is `Hashmap`? Some homegrown version of `HashMap`? --- Why is the code iterating all the fields of `getAPIJSONData`, when you only want to process the fields of the `SubSecData` object?

Comment: I am new to HashMaps. Just wrote the skeleton of it. I am still learning so need some help.

Comment: Could someone please help on this ?

Comment: That is still not Java. What is `for(getAPIJSONData.get("SubSecData"))` supposed to do? And the `}` end-brace is missing. And the `else` is missing a `{` start-brace. Please at least show valid code, so we know you know at least some Java.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. corrected the code now

Comment: In what way is `expectedKeyValuePairs.length` a *boolean* condition of the `for` loop? What's the point of the loop when you don't use `expectedKeyValuePairs` inside the loop?

Comment: Hi andreas .. not sure about the logic you are mentioning

Comment: Sure no prob @Andreas. I will correct this and will get some hands-on with java and will try to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i was able to come up with a solution for the problem. Below is the code which i have used.

```
for (int i = 0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonnew=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    HashMap<HashSet,Object> result = new ObjectMapper().readValue((DataInput) jsonnew, HashMap.class);
    log.info(result.toString());
    log.info(result);
    try
    {
        for (Object key : expectedKeyValuePairs.keySet())
        {
            if (result.containsKey(key))
            {
                result.get(key).equals(expectedKeyValuePairs.get(key));
                log.info("ExpectedKey" + key + "ExpectedValue" + expectedKeyValuePairs.get(key) + "ActualValue" + result.get(key));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace((PrintStream) key);
            log.info("failed during wait" + e);
            returnVal = false;
        }
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```

Thanks all for the support.